# View to show how far a cycle is from the current cycle

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table called cycle, that has the following structure:
id
starts_at
ends_at

the id is not unique, so its registered:

```
 id        starts_at            ends_at          cycle_year   cycle_number
 120       jan-01-2017          jan-05-2017         2017          1
 120       jan-06-2017          jan-11-2017         2017          2
 120       jan-12-2017          jan-18-2017         2017          3
```

What I need to do, its to create a view like this:

```
 id        starts_at            ends_at           how_far_it_is_from_newest
 120       jan-01-2017          jan-05-2017             2
 120       jan-06-2017          jan-11-2017             1
 120       jan-12-2017          jan-18-2017             0
```

Any ideas?

I have created this one, but it has a problem:

```
SET @counter = -1;
SELECT 
    *,
    concat(year, LPAD(number, 3, '0')) as 'cycle_ref', // eg. 2017001
    (@counter:=@counter + 1) as counter
FROM
    cycle
where
    id = 120
ORDER by 
    cycle_ref DESC
;
```

it return correctly, but if I take off the id=120, it will count regardless the id.

```
 id        starts_at            ends_at           how_far_it_is_from_newest
 120       jan-12-2017          jan-18-2017             0
 77        jan-16-2017          jan-28-2017             1 <-- wrong:should be 0
 120       jan-06-2017          jan-11-2017             2 <-- wrong:should be 1
 120       jan-01-2017          jan-05-2017             3 <-- wrong:should be 2
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

This worked to me:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS initCycleIndex;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION initCycleIndex() returns INT
BEGIN
    SET @counter:=-1;
    RETURN(@counter);
END $$
DELIMITER ;


DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getCycleIndex;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getCycleIndex() RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET @counter:= @counter + 1;
    return (@counter);
END $$
DELIMITER ;


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_cycle_indexed as

SELECT 
    c.*,
    concat(c.year, LPAD(c.number, 3, '0')) as 'cycle_ref',
    getCycleIndex() as 'index'
FROM
    cycle c
JOIN (select initCycleIndex()) r

ORDER by 
    cycle_ref DESC
;


#SELECT * FROM vw_cycle_indexed where id = 178;
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the problem with the counter not resetting at different IDs. Have a look at my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems to address here.

To initialize your variables you don't need functions. Just do it in a subquery (or in separate SET statements).

Biggest problem: You haven't defined an order to determine what's the newest entry. Your "how far it is from newest" might change every once in a while.

All you have implemented is a row counter. Of course it continues counting, regardless if the id is totally different. You have to have another variable that holds the value of the previous row. You can do so, by assigning the value of the current row to a variable **after** you've checked the value of the variable. The order in the select part is therefore very important.
The `IF()` function is quite simple, when the previous row id is different from the current row, return 0, otherwise the incremented row counter. And that's why it's also important to first order by id in the `ORDER` clause.

Have a try with this one:

```
SELECT 
    c.*,
    concat(year, LPAD(number, 3, '0')) as 'cycle_ref',
    @counter := IF(@prevID != id, 0, @counter + 1),
    @prevID := id
FROM
    cycle c
    , (SELECT @counter := -1, @prevID := NULL) var_init_subquery
ORDER by 
    id, ends_at DESC, cycle_ref
;
```

Only downside is, you can't use this statement in a VIEW, because variables aren't allowed there. I will try your approach with the functions, though. It might be a neat workaround.